# Compression done on 'text/html' but not 'application/xhtml+xml'?

Tags: html, apache, xhtml

I was creating a test page for myself to see what would trigger a strict xml parsing mode, and I came across an interesting piece of information.

My host seems to be compressing text/html, but not application/xhtml+xml.

If you would like to view this for yourself, point your browser to

http://m-p-w.org/projects/content/?xhtml

and

http://m-p-w.org/projects/content/?html

and view the results using using Chrome's inspector or Firebug.

I suppose my question is, "What kind of speed tradeoffs am I looking at? If compression is truly faster (as it would seem to be, since compression is the default), how can I force compression of certain content-types?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to be the relevant manual page: http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpGzipModule

Note `text/html` is always compressed. Other mime types need to be set on the `gzip_types` property.

---

By the way, according to [HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/infrastructure.html#xml), XML parsing mode should be used when the MIME type is

> ... text/xml, application/xml, and any MIME type whose subtype ends with
>   the four characters "+xml". [RFC3023]

Comment: Unless I'm very confused, this seems to be a manual entry for the nginx web server, and I'm using Apache.

Unless you're also recommending I switch to nginx...

Comment: OK. My mistake. Seems you're using nginx/varnish as a reverse proxy in front of Apache. Sorry, can't really tell what's currently doing the gzipping or where you'd like it done.

Comment: That's very odd, I just validated a page and you're right, the server comes up as "nginx/varnish." I was able to compress php output, which succeeds in the same way. 

Anyway, it looks like this is the right answer, even if my host doesn't let me access nginx settings. Thanks!